# Show data without duplicacy and count the duplicacy

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table as follows

> query :-
>
> ```
> Select ORDER_NO From Posuma Where CUST_CODE = '18'
> ```
>
> result :-
>
> ```
>  ORDER_NO 
>  ---------  
>  1014  
>  1029
> ```

now, i've search the other table name as polna for product which have related order no...

> query :-
>
> ```
> SELECT ITEM_CODE, ITEM_DESC, QTY FROM `polna` WHERE `ORDER_NO`=1014 ORDER BY `ORDER_NO` ASC
> ```
>
> result:-
>
> ```
> ITEM_CODE | ITEM_DESC    | QTY
> --------- | -------------| ----
> 32-224    | PLATE STAND  | 10                                   
> 32-227    | SCONCE       | 5                                    
> 32-244    | PLATE STAND  | 10                                   
> 32-245    | PLATE STAND  | 5
> ```

**I would like the following result:**

```
 ITEM_CODE | ITEM_DESC   | QTY
 --------- | ----------- | ----
 32-224    | PLATE STAND | 20
 32-245    | PLATE STAND | 10
 32-227    | SCONCE      | 5
```

Comment: use `group by` and `sum`!

Comment: ALREADY TRIED.... didn't find the appropriate result

Comment: group by item_code and item_desc?

Comment: SELECT ITEM_CODE, ITEM_DESC, SUM(QTY) FROM polna WHERE ORDER_NO=1014 GROUP BY item_code ORDER BY ORDER_NO ASC

Comment: want to make item code distinct, this should be repeated in table, and count the quantity if repeat more then one time

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query maybe useful for you.I think need to add GROUP BY in query.

```
SELECT ITEM_CODE, ITEM_DESC, SUM(QTY) as QTY FROM polna WHERE ORDER_NO=1014 GROUP BY ITEM_CODE ORDER BY ORDER_NO ASC
```

Try and let me know.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas Did you try above query. Because its display item code distinct, If more then one then it makes some other vise its display one time.

Comment: actually i have more then 10 order no, and all of then the repeated product. i have just trying then product shouldn't be repeat while i show them. and count the qty also if item code will repeat....

Comment: @SiddharthVyas can you please give me hole table so i can check it.